# Get the correct HTTP Status Code in PHP when website is protected against scraping by the Distill Network

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-301, http-status-codes, http-status-code-405

I am trying to get the redirect location of [a website](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/over-and-above-africa-the-solution-to-end-poaching-drones)

When I make a cURL request, I get a `405 Not Allowed` code in the response.

Using [SEOBook.com's Server Header Checker](http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/) the response is `200 OK`.

In my tests I only found [web-sniffer.net](http://web-sniffer.net/) to get the expected `301 Moved Permanently` status in the response.

I have tried a lot of different cURL configurations (user agent, cookies...) but no combination so far has been able to get the response I was expecting.

My code
        :

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/over-and-above-africa-the-solution-to-end-poaching-drones";
$timeout = 30;
$http = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13');
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

if (preg_match('`^https://`i', $url))
{
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
}

        curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($http,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept-Language', 'nl,en;q=0.7;en-us;q=0.3'));
$sContenu = curl_exec($http);

echo curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($http);
echo $sContenu;
?>
```

Comment: Provide the code that you've tried and didn't work for you.

Comment: And give examples of the configurations you've tried and why you chose them.

Comment: That SEOBook link gives a 301 as the response, as does curl from my terminal.